# User not being added to database with Devise Omniauth Facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

I have Devise user auth included in my site and it is working well.  I'm now trying to add Facebook authentication.

I'm able to login with FB, and the user is redirected back to my site ok.  When I check the connected apps in FB settings I can see my site is there listed.

The problem is that the FB is not added to my user table.  When I check the db, the provider and uid fields are blank, and site is still asking for the user to sign in.

*user.rb*

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :validatable,
  has_many :comments

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable,  :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]


  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      user.name = auth.info.name   # assuming the user model has a name
      #user.image = auth.info.image # assuming the user model has an image
      # If you are using confirmable and the provider(s) you use validate emails,
      # uncomment the line below to skip the confirmation emails.
      user.skip_confirmation!
    end
  end

  def self.new_with_session(params, session)
      super.tap do |user|
          if data = session["devise.facebook_data"] && session["devise.facebook_data"]["extra"]["raw_info"]
              user.email = data["email"] if user.email.blank?
          end
      end
  end

end
```

*Callback Controller*

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

  def facebook
  # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
  @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

  if @user.persisted?
    sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
    set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
  else
    session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    redirect_to new_user_registration_url
  end
end

def failure
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

*routes.rb*

```
#authentication
  devise_for :users, path: "auth", controllers: {
    sessions: 'users/sessions',
    registrations: 'users/registrations',
    unlocks: 'users/unlocks',
    omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks'
  }
```

*User Session Controller*

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
respond_to :js
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, :if => :devise_controller?


  protected

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  def configure_sign_in_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in, keys: [:attribute])
  end
end
```

*devise.rb*

```
     config.omniauth :facebook, '******', '*************', scope: "email", info_fields: 'email'
```

**Update**
Just caught the fact I have fname and lname fields in my user table, so have adjusted `user.rb` to reflect that:

`user.fname = auth.info.fname`

Comment: Try `first_or_create!`

Comment: I believe I'm doing that in my User model already.

`  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
`

Comment: With a bang `!`

Comment: ah right.  Unfortunately that's not solved it. db is still empty.

Comment: You can try this in rails console: `User.where(provider: 'facebook', uid: 'token1234').first_or_create do |user| ... end`. Does it create a user with correct provider and uid?

Comment: sorry I rarely use rails console.  What's the exact command I would need?

Comment: Open the terminal and run `rails console`. Then try creating a user by providing `provider` and `uid` in addition to other fields inside `do end` block.